# Trying to set wifi ap name and password, via an ssh session

Tags: ubuntu, raspi-config

This Pi has Ubuntu Mate on it. Everything I find says that raspi-config will have a setting in it for the wifi info but my version of raspi-config has a different menu and doesn't seem to have the wifi setting anywhere. Is there another version and if so where can I locate it?

[image]

Comment: What network manager do you have? E.g. with NM you could do this with `nmcli d wifi connect <SSID> password <password>`

Comment: This is amazing! and it almost worked @DmitryGrigoryev! I gave the command: `sudo nmcli d wifi connect "one boston" password 4444444444` and got this back `Device 'wlan0' successfully activated with 'b3d41cf5-df71-47ee-b640-e6d8d521ee2e'. But.. alas the wifi was not connected.  I think I am missing one last bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you have read apply to Raspbian.

Ubuntu MATE uses different networking and is normally configured via the GUI.

AFAIK there has not been a supported MATE since 16.04

Comment: There’s no cli way to do it (I mean without using Nani

Comment: ... without using nano to edit key files)?

Comment: @pitosalas I am not sure if you are trying to ask another Question, but if you are Comments are NOT the way to do it, and you need to provide more information about what ACTUAL version of OS you are using, how you installed it and what network manager it uses.